# Transparency or depth-test error in a really simpel two-pass effect

Tags: opengl, rendering, glsl, jogl

I want to setup a really simple two-pass effect. The  first pass draws a texture object to a texture. The second pass creates a full screen quad in the geometry shader and textures it with the texture written in pass one.

The texture and framebuffer is set up in the following way:

```
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBufferHandle, 0);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferHandle[0]);

texture = new Texture(gl, new TextureData(gl.getGLProfile(), GL3.GL_RGB, viewportWidth, viewportHeight,
    0, GL3.GL_RGB, GL3.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, false, false, null, null));
texture.setTexParameteri(gl, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL3.GL_LINEAR);
texture.setTexParameteri(gl, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL3.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glFramebufferTexture(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture.getTextureObject(), 0);

int drawBuffers[] = {GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
gl.glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers, 0);

if (gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    throw new Exception("error while creating framebuffer");
```

The render function looks like:

```
// 1st pass
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferHandle[0]);
gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f); 
gl.glClear(GL3.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

texturePass.apply();
texturePass.updatePerObject(world);
texturePass.updateTexture(object.getDiffuseMap());
object.draw(gl);    

// 2nd pass
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f); 
gl.glClear(GL3.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

fullscreenQuadPass.apply();
fullscreenQuadPass.updateTexture(texture)
```

;
gl.glDrawArrays(GL3.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

The picture below shows the result of applying this effect:
[image: Render-to-Texture error]

As you hopefully can see, one can see through the golem and see his right hand. It seems like there is some kind of depth-test or transparency error.

Everything looks fine if I comment the 2nd pass out and replace

```
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferHandle[0]);
```

by

```
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Does anyone have an idea, what goes on here?

**EDIT**: In fact, I'm actually missing a depth buffer for the 2nd pass. Thus, I've updated my initialization sequence to

```
// Create framebuffer
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBufferHandle, 0);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferHandle[0]);

// Set up color texture
colorTexture = new Texture(gl, new TextureData(gl.getGLProfile(),
    GL4.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL4.GL_RGBA, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        false, false, false, null, null));
gl.glFramebufferTexture(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL4.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    colorTexture.getTextureObject(), 0);

// Create and set up depth renderbuffer
gl.glGenRenderbuffers(GL4.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferHandle, 0);
gl.glBindRenderbuffer(GL4.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferHandle[0]);
gl.glRenderbufferStorage(GL4.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL4.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
    width, height);
gl.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL4.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
    GL4.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferHandle[0]);

int drawBuffers[] = {GL4.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
gl.glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers, 0);
```

However, now my system crashes with a "fatal error" by the Java Runtime Environment. If I comment the newly added lines out, everything "works fine". What's the point now?

**EDIT2**: I've no idea why I've written

```
gl.glGenRenderbuffers(GL4.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferHandle, 0);
```

Of course, it should be

```
gl.glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthRenderBufferHandle, 0);
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Framebuffer Object currently lacks a depth attachment.

#### Here is some C pseudo-code that will address your problem:

```
GLuint depth_rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers (1, &depth_rbo);

glBindRenderbuffer (GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_rbo);

glRenderbufferStorage     (GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,  width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER,  GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_rbo);
```

In fact, it also lacks a stencil attachment, so I am not sure why you are clearing the stencil buffer?

If you have stencil operations to perform you will need to allocate storage for it as well. Moreover, if you need ***both*** depth and stencil in an FBO, you must use a packed **Depth-Stencil** format ([`GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Object_Structure)).

Comment: You're right. Clearing the stencil buffer doesn't make sense. Just to be sure that you've got me right: All I want to do, is rendering a textured object to a texture and color a full screen quad with this texture (such that the result looks exactly like if it were rendered directly to the screen).

So, I'm only interested in storing the color values to a texture while the depth doesn't need to be stored (but each pixel should have passed the depth test, before colored).

So, do I really need to generate another (render) buffer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Without this, when you draw into the FBO there is no depth buffer. That means there is no way to depth test anything, so whatever is drawn last is what shows up. You actually don't need a depth buffer for your 2nd pass (though I suspect you have one), but you absolutely need one for the 1st pass.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've edited my question. After adding the lines you mentioned, my application crashes on start.

Comment: I finally found the error. I've no idea why, but I've written `gl.glGenRenderbuffers(GL4.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferHandle, 0);` what does not make too much sense.